# Android HTML5 video is not shutdown after destroying WebView

Tags: android, html5-video, android-webview

I've got an issue with WebView on Android 3.1 and higher. I have a WebView with the `<video>` tag in my activity and it plays without any problems.  When the activity `onDestroy()` is called I'm calling `destroy()` on  the WebView to stop the video. Everything works fine.

The issue occurs when I press play, then switch into fullscreen, exit fullscreen and press play again. Then I destroy the Activity and WebView, but the video is still running—why?

I call the callback from `onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback)` when I return from fullscreen.

The video sound stops when I open the same or other video.

How can I shutdown everything when I'm done with the current Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading blank page when destroying activity works.

Comment: Hi Mikoos, where did you exactly set this? In the onPause, onStop or onDestroy? Did you use webView.loadUrl("about:blank"); ?

Comment: I've put empty html page in assets. I can't remember when I was opening that page.